# StreamBuilder ListView with timer

Tags: flutter, listview, stream-builder

in my Flutter project i am using a StreamBuilder to fetch posts from Firebase Firestore and i am displaying the posts in a ListView, every time a post is added or delete the ListView displays update list of Posts.
I set an expiry Timestamp for each post and in my ListView i set a Countdown timer to display remaining time for the post. When first launching the app the count down timers in the ListView are displayed correctly, but when a new post is added or deleted the list view duplicates the Timer, as if it displays the time for the deleted post.

```
if (_postObjectsList.isNotEmpty) ...[
          ListView.builder(
            primary: true,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: _postObjectsList.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              final PostObject postObject = _postObjectsList[index];

              return StatusTile(
                postTime: postObject.timestamp.toDate(),
                currentUserMember: false,
                infoTapped: () => _downloadRestInfo(
                    postObject.restaurantId,
                    context,
                    statusLoadState,
                    restaurantDatabaseService),
                postObject: postObject,
                appUser: userData.getCurrentUser,
                statusTileType: StatusTileType.type,
                
              );
            },
          )
        ],
```

I am struggling with this for 2 days and i am unable to resolve the issue.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=askdbIN.com
Check out this, you may find here :)